# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: mysql, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una practica con reatjs, expreesjs y Mysql. Mientras estaba realizando la practica de repente sale un error que he tratado de resolverlo buscando por internet pero nada me funciona.

Al principio yo ejecutaba la aplicación con **Vitejs**. Mientras buscaba información, se comentaba en los foros que investigue que era un error en **Vitejs** y que algunos lo resolvieron pasando sus proyectos de **Vitejs** a **CRA** (**Create-React-App**). Yo hice esa migración, por así llamarlo, y aun así da el mismo error. Otros dicen que tiene que ver con el **Buffer**, la verdad  que busque sobre el dichoso **Buffer** y la información que me aprecia era que de instalaba y se importaba en el **main.js, index.js o main.ts** para **typescrip**t pero aun así nada funciona.

Gracias de ante mano

[image: esta es una imagen del error que me sale por la consola del navegador, sale tanto Firefox como en Chrome]